# Set a datagridview button color and text on click

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I create a button column on my datagrid on click:

```
    Private Sub btnRemoveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRemoveItem.Click

    Dim column As DataGridViewButtonColumn
    grdNewInvoice.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    column = New DataGridViewButtonColumn
    grdNewInvoice.Columns.Add(column)

End Sub
```

I am trying to access the column's property to set the color and text on each row. How can I do that?

Comment: You want to set your button's text? And your button's color? Or do you want to set the cell's background color?

Comment: Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/51128/Change-individual-DataGridView-row-colors-based-on